# Adobe Acrobat Reader and Foxit reader show PDF Signature Valid but iText7 says otherwise

Tags: c#, itext, adobe, itext7

I have a signed PDF file from my client, which contains 2 signatures and is totally valid when opened with Adobe Acrobat Reader and Foxit Reader. But I'm using iText7 (C#) to verify those signatures and get false while verifying the second signature.

Below is my code:

```cs
public static async Task VefifySignaturePDFFile(Stream mStream)
{
    try
    {
        using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(mStream, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.ReaderProperties()))
        {
            using (var oStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader))
                {
                    iText.Signatures.SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new iText.Signatures.SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
                    iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm acroForm = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
                    if (signatureUtil.GetSignatureNames().Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (String name in signatureUtil.GetSignatureNames())
                        {
                            #region Kiểm tra chữ ký trong file
                            iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = null;
                            var sig = signatureUtil.GetSignature(name);
                            var cover = signatureUtil.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name);
                            var llX = float.Parse(acroForm.GetFormFields()[name].GetWidgets().First().GetRectangle().Get(0).ToString());
                            var llY = float.Parse(acroForm.GetFormFields()[name].GetWidgets().First().GetRectangle().Get(1).ToString());
                            var urX = float.Parse(acroForm.GetFormFields()[name].GetWidgets().First().GetRectangle().Get(2).ToString()) - llX;
                            var urY = float.Parse(acroForm.GetFormFields()[name].GetWidgets().First().GetRectangle().Get(3).ToString()) - llY;
                            var page = pdfDocument.GetPageNumber(acroForm.GetFormFields()[name].GetWidgets().First().GetPage());
                            var reason = sig.GetReason();
                            try
                            {
                                pkcs7 = signatureUtil.ReadSignatureData(name); // Chữ ký bị lỗi thì sẽ nhẩy vào ex
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            var verify = pkcs7.VerifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity(); // Tài liệu bị thay đổi sẽ ra false
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
   }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bvk5EckUrJ-dzehhQJyBGkM4QLrIF3Uk/view?usp=sharing

Here is the link leading to my PDF file

Comment: eSig DSS also determines that the second signature is invalid. Most likely just another case where Adobe Acrobat is too lax.

Comment: Hi @mkl, thank for your response. If this this the case, how can I determine exactly whether the signature itself is invalid or the file is modified using iText, because the VerifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity method only return true or false

Comment: I analyzed the signature, see my answer. In a nutshell, the second signature has a questionable structure resulting in ambiguities, depending on whether one strictly follows RFCs (like iText in this case) or not (like Acrobat here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in the second signature: Its embedded CMS signature container has this `EncapsulatedContentInfo` entry:

```
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 data (PKCS #7)
    [0] (1 elem)
      OCTET STRING (0 byte)
```

In particular this entry has an `eContent` value, the 0-tagged `OCTET STRING (0 byte)`, i.e. a byte array of length zero.

According to RFC 3852 and RFC 5652 (which the PDF specifications ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2 respectively reference as CMS specification), `eContent` - if present - contains the signed data. Only if `eContent` is not present, the signed data is outside the CMS container.

Thus, your second signature strictly said claims that it signs an empty byte array and not the PDF document it is embedded in.

You mention that Adobe Acrobat and Foxit validate the signature. Apparently these validators disregard the misleading `eContent` entry, maybe because the contained byte array is empty. iText and eSig DSS, on the other hand, strictly follow the RFCs, consider the `eContent` entry in their validation routine and consequentially run into a validation failure.

Comment: Thank you, can I determine exactly whether the signature itself is invalid or the file is modified after sigining using iText?

Comment: Well, that is difficult. One can quite simply patch iText to react differently to misleading `eContent` entries but that would cover only the specific problem in the signature here. Other invalid structures would have to be recognized differently.